# ESD Voltage for diode - Positive and negative transients

Tags: voltage, current, diodes, esd, clamp

While selecting ESD protection diodes for, say, ethernet or usb datalines, we usually select the clamping voltage of the diode more than the working voltage of the signal lines and lesser than the absolute maximum voltage of those pins. We need to select a clamping voltage of the diode within that band, right?

For example, if the working voltage of the data lines is 3V and the absolute maximum rating of the pin is 5V, we need to select an esd clamping voltage diode between 3V to 5V, right?

But this would take care of positive transients, right? For example, if the absolute maximum rating of the pin is -0.5V to 6V, and I select a [clamping voltage diode](https://semtech.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#E0000000JelG/a/2R0000001TBb/1Sb_xwpUbvH6q70WnqQwnuIuQfNX7THrFXZCKGHIIn8) of 3.3V, this would take care of positive transients.

What about negative transients? For the negative transients, we need to restrict the clamping voltage to -0.5V, right? In that case, I searched a couple of ESD diode datasheets. Even though they are bidirectional, they don't have any graphs.

Is it right to expect that for a bidirectional ESD clamping diode, that says it has a positive clamping voltage of 3.3V, would it be correct to assume that its negative clamping voltage would be -3.3V?

If that's the case, what should we do if the pin's absolute rating is only-0.5V? What protection clamping diode's voltage we can use?

Edit:

This [diode](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PESD1LIN.pdf) seems to have different clamping voltages for both ends of the diode. But both are positive clamping voltages only, right? Please tell me how to understand this diode clamping voltages too.

Comment: Why would ethernet data lines require ESD protection? Magnetic interfaces protect the PHY so maybe you need to explain your specific application?

Comment: The PESD1LIN diode you link to is related to protection from automotive over/under voltages that could result from such things as a reverse battery condition or an incorrect jump start.  This is the reasoning for the asymmetrical (-15/+24V) protection.